# Qt data visualization background image and transparency support

Tags: qt, qml, data-visualization

Does the data visualization module support background image especially [`Surface3D`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtdatavisualization-surface3d.html) element , also is there any why to apply transparency to plot color. Basically I need to place an image on x-z plane and draw surface plot above it with some transparency, so the user can see the background image through the surface plot.

Comment: I am looking for the same information. Did you find a way to make that background transparent? I posted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42971495/qml-surface3d-windowcolor.

Comment: No, I didn't get the solution. But I have used `drawMode: Surface3DSeries.DrawWireframe` for  `Surface3DSeries` so I was able to see through the plot.

Comment: OK, thanks. I assume the transparency for this background is not implemented yet, but it's a bit awkward as we can change its color! So, let's be patient.